# What does '今のところ、目につくものは何もない。' translate to?

Tags: compound-verbs, japanese-to-english

I'm thinking it might be 'So far, there was nothing for the eyes to focus on (attach to, arrive on). The ’つくもの’ without kanji is throwing me off.

Or maybe it's something like: 'So far, there's no destination in sight'.

The character in the book I'm reading is wandering to a train station.

Am I close?

Answer (score 2):

「つく」does correspond to several words, but 「目につく」is 「目に付く」, meaning "to attract attention" or "to be noticeable", with 「付く」rendered either in kana or kanji. 「もの」just means "thing".

> 今のところ、目につくものは何もない。

means

> So far, there is nothing noticeable at all.

Or

> For now, nothing has stood out/caught my attention.